# Semantic-ui: How to use the 'animateChildren'-Behavior of a Accordion?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic-ui on my website and trying to implement an accordion. Since I have a script tag in the accordion some JS is visible, according to this [site](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3171) it is a bug and the quick solution is to use the behavior `animateChildren: false`.

But I have no clue how to set this behavior, on the semantic-ui website of [accordions](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#/usage) is an example:

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion('behavior', argumentOne, argumentTwo...);
```

When I tried:

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion('animateChildren', false);
```

I got an error.
So what is the correct way to call it?

Edit: So I find out the Solution by myselfe. If anyone else have the same problem, the Solution is:

```
$('.ui.styled.fluid.accordion')
        .accordion({
            animateChildren: false
        })
    ;
```